# Use variables in Terraform on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

This is `setup.tf`

```
data "google_compute_network" "selected" {
  name = "${var.network}"
}
```

It's very basic. I just want to create a network in Google Cloud.
I run this with:

```
terraform apply -var 'network=net1'
```

But I still got an error like:

```
Error: resource 'data.google_compute_network.selected' config: unknown variable referenced: 'network'; define it with a 'variable' block
```

When I don't use variables in works like expected.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should have the variable defined to get terraform not complain about it.

```
    variable "network" {
      description = "your description goes here"
      type = "string/map/list/boolean"
      default = "default value here"
    }
```

You can put this in your main file or may be in a separate file called input.tf but it just has to be present in the same directory.

`terraform apply -var 'your-var=your-value'` will override the value of the default in the variable section.

Terraform Doc: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html